# how to add a textfield on last row in tableview in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, tableview

when i press the new button i need to add a textfield on last row of tableview.

can any one explain the flow.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just i tried this scenario.

Create a one Boolean variable like this
BOOL newButtonPress = NO;

then fallow the below code

```
-(IBAction)newButtonClicked:(id)sender{
if (self.newButtonPress == NO) {
//if new button press then newbuttpress is yes and reload the tableview
self.newButtonPress = YES;
[self .reloadTableview reloadData];
    }   
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
if(self.newButtonPress == YES)//creating noOfRows when newbutton pressed
{
    return [self.itemNames count]+1;
}
else {
    return [self.itemNames count]; 
   }
}
```

Then add the below code into the cellForRowAtIndexPath method

```
//when new button is pressed adding new cell
if (self.newButtonPress == YES) {
    if([self.itemNames count] == [indexPath row]){
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        //creating the textfield if new button is pressed 
        UITextField *extraField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 6, 100, 30)];
        extraField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
        extraField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        [extraField becomeFirstResponder];
        [extraField setDelegate:self];
        [cell addSubview:extraField];
        [extraField release];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am very new to iphone coding,i want to share my thoughts. If that is wrong please ignore.

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method u need to set a `textfield` in 
`if(indexPath.row==numberOfRows-1)` condition.
In button pressed method u can set `textField.hidden=NO` and in `viewdidload` `textField.hidden=YES`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the text field to appear at the end of the table, why not consider using UITableview's tableFooterView property?

In that case you don't have to ensure that you return the UITextField in your delegate methods.

You should nearly be able to drag drop a new UITextField in your Tableview if you are using InterfaceBuilder or XCode 4.